# SpringBoot map yaml to map of map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

Is it possible to inject below yaml file to Spring Boot application as `Map<String, Map<String, String>` where `tradeType` will be the key of outer map and P and B will be the key value for inner map for.

```
tradeType:
    P: B
    S: S
securityCode: 
    ICI: ICICI Bank
    BOB: Bank of Baroda
    BOA: Bank of America
    BOS: Bank of Singapore
```

As suggested this is how my class look.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:data/referenceDataMapping.yaml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "map")
public class ReferenceDataMapping {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> entries;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (entries != null) {
            logger.info(entries.toString());
            return entries.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(Map<String, Map<String, String>> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

}
```

> from build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:2.23.1'
    compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-quartz2:2.23.1'
    compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.23.1'
    compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jacksonxml:2.23.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    compile 'net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:9.9.1-1'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.1.3.RELEASE'
}
```

> referenceDataMapping.yaml

```
    map: 
   entries:
      tradeType:
          P: B
          S: S
      securityCode: 
          ICI: ICICI Bank
          BOB: Bank of Baroda
          BOA: Bank of America
          BOS: Bank of Singapore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. It is possible.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="map")
public class Test {

    private Map<String,Map<String,String>> entires;

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getEntires() {
        return entires;
    }

    public void setEntires(Map<String, Map<String, String>> entires) {
        this.entires = entires;
    }

}
```

**application.yml**:

```
map:
  entires:
    tradeType:
      P: B
      S: S
    securityCode: 
      ICI: ICICI Bank
      BOB: Bank of Baroda
      BOA: Bank of America
      BOS: Bank of Singapore
```

output:

```
{tradeType={P=B, S=S}, securityCode={ICI=ICICI Bank, BOB=Bank of Baroda, BOA=Bank of America, BOS=Bank of Singapore}}
```

**Update:**

As described in this [github-issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9104). **@PropertySource doesnt support yaml files**. In that case, kindly follow this guide [PropertySource-with-yaml-files](https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/)

Comment: Thanks Barath ! I tried as suggested by you but my map is null even after application is up. Is there any dependency i need to include in my gradle ?

Comment: share the entries of this file referenceDataMapping.yaml

Comment: configurationproperties will work only if its in application ymls.

Comment: Oh is it. As I could read here , [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9104) It doesnt support .yaml extension. But I could see it is working fine incase of .properties as mentioned here [stack-47042237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042237/i-am-using-a-combination-of-propertysource-and-configurationproperties-but-i-w)

Comment: It's not working for me, i tried exactly same as Barath suggested. Please refer the original post with code, yaml and gradle

Comment: @JigarNaik as mentioned here in the issue, it doesnt support yaml configuration. Secondly it doesnt have ```referenceData``` key.

Comment: changed to .properties with entries it is working fine for me ```map.entires.tradeType.P=B
map.entires.tradeType.S=S```

Comment: yes, i changed it to entries and it was not working, after moving content of referenceDataMapping.yaml to application.yaml it's working now. `map: 
   entries:
      tradeType:
          P: B
          S: S
      securityCode: 
          ICI: ICICI Bank
          BOB: Bank of Baroda
          BOA: Bank of America
          BOS: Bank of Singapore`

Answer (score 1):

If the YAML is in different file than application.yml,

```
@Component
public class YourClass {


    private Map<String, String> tradeType;
    private Map<String, String> securityCode;

    public Map<String, String> getTradeType() {
        return tradeType;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSecurityCode() {
        return securityCode;
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void yamlFactory() {
        YamlMapFactoryBean factory = new YamlMapFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(new ClassPathResource("your.yml"));
        tradeType = (Map<String, String>) factory.getObject().get("tradeType");
        securityCode = (Map<String, String>) factory.getObject().get("securityCode");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are looking for... I had faced lots of difficulty in getting this right 1 year ago :)

Comment: Let me try this way, i dont want to declare tradeType and securityCode, i want it to be dynamic as per the yaml, that's why i am choosing map of map.

Comment: then, you wrap it in a parent key, (my-outer-map with maps inside) and changing type to Map<String,Map<String,String>>

Comment: here's my yaml validator, if you would like to try: http://varkeys-rhel-jenkins.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:8090/editor

Comment: here is my version of yamlFactory to return generic map  `@PostConstruct
 public void yamlFactory() {
  YamlMapFactoryBean factory = new YamlMapFactoryBean();
  factory.setResources(new ClassPathResource("referenceDataMapping.yaml"));
  Map<String, Object> map = factory.getObject();
  entries = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (Map<String, String>) e.getValue()));
  logger.info("map : " + entries.get("tradeType").get("P"));
 }`  Thanks ! Anand & Barath !